# How an autocorrelation function is calculated experimentally in a Dynamic Light Scattering experiment

Tags: scattering, correlation-functions

As said in the title, I would like to know how an autocorrelation function of scattered light intensities defined as $G(\tau)=\langle I(t)I(t+\tau)\rangle$ is computed experimentally. Let's say we have a sample of spherical nanoparticles completely monodisperse and we irradiate the cuvette which contains this sample with a laser and we collect the scattering light with a single detector. Due to Brownian motion, we do expect that the plot of intensity vs. time would be like in the image below.

[image]

Now my question is: **how the autocorrelation function is experimentally measured?**

Do we have to measure the scattered intensity at time $t_1$, than at time $t_2>t_1$ and make the product between the 2?
Or, do we measure the intensity with the detector for a certain interval of time, then we set a certain $\tau$, we translate the function $I vs. t$ of a certain quantity $\tau$ and we do the product $I(t)I(t+\tau)$ for every $t$?
If so, how can we obtain from this the typical correlation function we get in these kind of experiments (which I report in the image)? Why does it go to zero for large $\tau$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The spherical nanoparticles in the completely monodisperse solution you describe will undergo brownian motion aka "random walks" through space. This random movement of a particle is described by the probability distribution:

$$ P(r,t|0,0) = \frac{1}{\left (4\pi D t \right )^{3/2}} e^{-r^2/4Dt} $$

Where $D = \frac{k_BT}{6\pi \eta a}$

Where $T$ is the temperature of the fluid the nanoparticles are submerged in, $\eta$ is the viscosity, and a is the nanoparticle radius.

If we shine a laser with constant intensity $I_{In}$ into the cuvette, laser light will scatter off the nanoparticles with an electric field:

$$ E(t) = E_0 \sum_{k}e^{i\left (\phi_{k}(t) -\omega t\right )}$$
Where the sum is over the particles which scatter light. The intensity will then vary as a function of time due to the phase difference between the components of the scatter field from each particle:

$$ I_{Out}(t) = C|E(t)|^2$$

Since the particles move under Brownian motion, the phase differences change randomly resulting in a randomly fluctuating intensity trace such as what your diagram shows.

Suppose we take a measurement of the intensity $I_{Out}(0)$ at time $t=0$. At this moment in time the particles are at positions $\{\vec{r}_1, ..., \vec{r}_{N}\}$. At a 'short' time later $t=\epsilon$ the particles move by a 'small' amount $ \{ \vec{r}_1 + \epsilon\vec{v}_1, ..., \vec{r}_{N} + \epsilon\vec{v}_N \}$ and so the phases also change by a 'small' amount. The result of this motion is a new intensity $I_{Out}(\epsilon)$ which is near the original value and could be predicted within some tolerance. Over longer times however, the random motion of the particles makes it impossible to predict the intensity given $I_{Out}(0)$.

The question is then how long does it take for the intensity to become impossible to predict, or another way of putting it, how long until the intensity is no longer correlated with its past history? We can see that faster moving particles will more rapidly deviate from their initial conditions, causing the intensity to more rapidly fluctuate and de-correlate from its initial conditions. This is also demonstrated by the diagram you attached. The speed of the nanoparticles is determined by the diffusion coefficient $D$ and so we there is a link between the self correlation of the intensity and the diffusivity of the nanoparticles.

This is where the autocorrelation, $G(\tau) = \langle I(t)I(t+\tau)\rangle$ comes in. The autocorrelation gives us a quantitative measurement for how fast the de-correlation described above happens. It also links the intensity measurements to the diffusivity mathematically.

We compute the autocorrelation by taking the product $I(t)I^{*}(t+\tau)$ and then averaging over the probability ensemble outlined above. The result of this computation is:

$$ G(\tau) = N^2 I_{0}^2 \left ( 1 + e^{-2DK^2\tau} \right )$$

The details of this derivation can be found in this great [paper](https://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/courses/physics_173_273/Light_scattering_benedek_paper.pdf).

A more useful quantity is the the normalized autocorrelation which removes the baseline intensity and normalization factors from consideration:

$$ g(\tau) = \frac{G(\tau)}{\langle I(t)^2 \rangle} = 1 + e^{-2DK^2\tau} $$

With this equation we see how the normalized autocorrelation exponentially decays to a value of 1, due to the process described above. The rate of decay is determined by the diffusion coefficient $D$ and a scattering parameter $K=\frac{4n\pi}{\lambda}\sin(\theta/2)$. In this equation $n$ is the index of refraction, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light, and $\theta$ is the scattering angle. By fitting the autocorrelation with an exponential decay and applying the scattering and liquid parameters one can determine the size of the nanoparticles.

With this machinery in place, the final question is how do we measure the autocorrelation experimentally? We can take measurements of the intensity $I(t)$ and then take advantage of the [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) to compute the corresponding autocorrelation. This theorem gives us a means to compute the autocorrelation from the spectral power density. Specifically:

We can take the fourier transform of the intensity (which can be done numerically with a fast fourier transform):
$$\hat{I}(f) = \int_{-\inf}^{\inf} e^{-i \omega t}I(t) dt$$

Then the spectral power density is defined as:

$$ S_{I}(f) = |\hat{I}(f)|^2$$

Finally, the Weiner-Khinchin theorem tells us that:

$$ G(\tau) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i\tau \omega} S_{I}(\omega) d\omega$$

Giving you a means to compute the autocorrelation from experimental data.